# Wordpress new created sub category page redirects to 404 page

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, categories

Website having more than 135 categories/ subcategories.

It is working fine with existing subcategory page but If I create any new subcategory or change slug for already existing subcategory(which is working fine), it redirects to 404 page.

Ex: http://overseasattractions.com/pacific/australia/melbourne/ is working fine.
but if i try to change slug for 'melbourne' it redirects to 404 page.

Ex: http://overseasattractions.com/pacific/australia/adelaide/

This is the new created subcategory under the same parent category but it redirects to 404.

Please help as I am not much aware or wordpress and such redirections.

Comment: What you have set as permalink structure?

Comment: permalink structure is /%category%/%postname%/

Comment: Can you thy this please : /%category%/%subcategory%/%postname%/

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, yes we tried but it can't be work

Comment: ok then it could be any problem..have you upgrade wp version recently? or did you move your site from one to another domain? Once set default permalink and check if it works?

Comment: Its been more than a month back I upgraded the wordpress. Even afterwards I added several categories/subcategories and it was working well. But since last few days I am facing such strange issue.

Comment: Please try using default permalink once , also do you using any plugin for permalink? for ex : advance permalink?

Comment: default permalink works fine!, no plugin using for permalinks

Comment: if default permalink fine and its issue of custom permalink structure or any other thing which may by you have specified for links in .htaccess..

Comment: No, I haven't specified anything in .htaccess. And if I would have it should apply for all the cases/categories/subcategories.

Comment: Oh..then no more idea. last thing you can try to clear cache of your wp. by using cache plugin then try.

Answer (score 0):

If you Change permalink on site then must update all category with new permalink then you are able to display category and work properly on site.

otherwise you go with existing permalink on site and add new category or sub category.